# web apps: modules speaking with each others

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, web-applications, scope

I'm building a web app. My code is inside this usual:

```
;(function($) {
//a lot of code
})(jQuery);
```

My problem now is that I'd like to split this code in more files, each with its "local" scope like above. What's the best way then to do this, taking in account that maybe code blocks in the different files should communicate with each other?

Comment: Are you know about backbonejs MVC js framework ?

Comment: Yes I will use backbone and some code of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create commonJS modules. The best option for you is to use requireJS. Easy to set up and configure.

http://requirejs.org/‎

Comment: Yes, I've opted for require.js - sort of commonJS evolution and really well done.